# Windows Phone 8 image flick event not working

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8

I have the following code in my xaml in a Windows phone 8 page..

```
  <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Name="img" Width="350" Height="480" Margin="0,40,0,0">
                        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                            <toolkit:GestureListener Flick="GestureListener_Flick"></toolkit:GestureListener>
                        </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    </Image>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
```

CS file code:

```
public void View()
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {

                    pics = new List<string>();
                    pics = (List<string>)Application.Current.Resources["Photolist"];
                    img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=" + pics[imagenm] + "&key=AIzaSyDnoBLK2Zk46LRPb1qRQYJIVRoUvBeo5tA"));
                });
        }

        private void GestureListener_Flick(object sender, FlickGestureEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.HorizontalVelocity > 0)
            {
                value +=imagenm;
                img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=" + pics[value] + "&key=AIzaSyDnoBLK2Zk46LRPb1qRQYJIVRoUvBeo5tA"));
            }
        }

        private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                imagenm = Convert.ToInt32(NavigationContext.QueryString["imgname"]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            View();
        }
```

Now i am able to display the user selected image from the previous window perfectly. But when I flick right nothing seems to happen. Please help why the flick event on image is not firing. Thanks.